# Ant with JavaMail: authentication required

Tags: java, batch-file, ant, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to start ant from .bat-file like this:

```
java -classpath "<ant_lib_jars>" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher <ant_command_line_args>
```

Ant was added to project with all additional libraries (including JavaMail jars). After start batch script will collect all necessary jars and create string for classpath (`<ant_lib_jars>`). All command line arguments will be passed to Launcher class "as is".

This approach correctly works for all targets in my build file except target which use mail task. This target looks like this:

```
<target name="testtarget">
    <mail
            ssl="true"
            mailhost="smtp.gmail.com"
            mailport="465"
            user="<gmail_user>"
            password="<gmail_password>"
            subject="Subject"
            >
        <from address="<gmail_address>"/>
        <to address="<recipient_address>"/>
        <message src="<message_file>"/>
    </mail>
</target>
```

When i start `ant -v testtarget` from command line, i get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
....
Problem while sending mime mail:
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer.send(MimeMailer.java:261)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.EmailTask.execute(EmailTask.java:574)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 m5sm23576192laj.4 - gsmtp
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer.send(MimeMailer.java:258)
        ... 18 more
```

The same error occures if ant can't find mail.jar (from JavaMail) in classpath. So i tried to specify "-lib" flag with path to mail.jar and it doesn't work.

Attempt to start this target with the same ant but not through .bat-file was finished successful - email letter was sent:

```
<full_path_to_project_ant>/bin/ant -lib ant/lib/mail.jar testtarget
```

Setting up `ignoreInvalidRecipients` attribute with `true` value ends up with another error:

```
BUILD FAILED
....
Couldn't reach any recipient
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer.send(MimeMailer.java:264)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.EmailTask.execute(EmailTask.java:574)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 go4sm23006946lbc.3 - gsmtp
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer.send(MimeMailer.java:258)
        ... 18 more
```

Recipient address is absolutely correct that is confirmed by starting target not through .bat-file with the same credentials.

I tried to rebuild ant-launcher.jar from ant sources with additional logging and found that mail.jar falls into ant classpath. `SendFailedException` rises on sending message using SMTPS.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've got it. The reason of such unobvious behaviour was in the ant classloading model. My email.jar (from JavaMail) file lie in `ANT_HOME/lib` directory and in those directory was file `mail-1.4.jar` (which was downloaded after starting fetch.xml build file, it's needed to download all libraries for optional tasks). This jar file is something like stub and doesn't support all mail features. In this case, i suppose, ant core classloader will find needed classes in `mail-1.4.jar`. So i removed this file and now my target works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in some environments and not others, then there must be something different about the configurations.  Maybe you're using a different JavaMail jar file in one environment?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, in all cases JavaMail jar is the same. All difference consists in a manner of starting ant.

Comment: I can't even begin to guess why that would make a difference.  It might be helpful if there was a way to enable JavaMail debugging when running from ant.  You could try setting the Java System property "mail.debug" to "true" when invoking ant.  Or perhaps there's an undocumented "debug" attribute on the ant mail task, or a way to set JavaMail Session properties for the ant task?

Comment: I tried to set "mail.debug" to "true" but didn't see any additional output. `-diagnostics` flag shows that property was correctly set. Moreover, i delved into ant sources and didn't find any undocumented properties which will set `Session.setDebug(true)` or something similar for JavaMail.

Comment: Looks like you may have to rebuild the ant plugin in order to debug this.

Comment: I added answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120791/ant-with-javamail-authentication-required/20185282#20185282)